# MySql - in one query how to get the Count of records by daywise, monthwise, yearwise and total records all time

Tags: mysql

i have a table where users enters data in every day basis

I need the query (in one query)  to the get the total number of records entered per day, per month, per year and all total group by user

any suggestions??

### example output

```
username   count(today)   count(month)  count(year) count(*)
user1          10           100          1000       2300
user2           5           70            730        1240
```

Comment: show your table structure and sample data atleast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count, CASE and Group by will do it for you:

```
select user_name, sum(case when curdate()=date_time then 1 end) Today, 
sum(case when Month(curdate())=Month(date_time) then 1 end) Month,
sum(case when year(curdate())=year(date_time) then 1 end) Year, 
count(*) 
from table1
group by user_name;
```

[REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/EGHD96478)

Comment: No, It is displaying the same count for all fields  'code'  entryby  count(CURDATE())  count(month(date_entered))  count(year(date_entered))  count(*)  
user1  727  727  727  727
user2  144  144  144  144

Comment: @Praveen Modified the answer

Comment: @G one -Thanks it working great, but a small correction    select entryby, sum(case when date_entered >= curdate() then 1 end) Today, sum(case when Month(curdate())=Month(date_entered) then 1 end) Month, sum(case when year(curdate())=year(date_entered) then 1 end) Year, count(*) from jobs group by entryby